# stop npm test clear output

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs

I am running `npm test` on a react project, that runs unit tests using `jest` and `react testing library`.  The log of tests (including console log lines that I added to debug) is printed and then deleted after running the tests (probably being deleted after each test or at some limit). finally a summary of the run is shown but it does not help understand the issue.

how can I stop my npm test output being deleted?

Answer (score 1):

nevermind, it was the default terminal (iterm) scrollback buffer limit, which is 1000 lines.  apparently, after a fresh setup,  the first time I hit the limit was the tests.

here is how to make it unlimited.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also pipe the output of the terminal to a file eg

`npm run test >> mytest.txt`